Why do HEAD and HEAD^ show the same commit id in cmd.exe?
I am new to git and trying to understand HEAD and HEAD^. When I am trying to do git rev-parse, I am seeing both HEAD and HEAD^ showing the same commit id.
Note: Latest commit is a merge commit happened by merging a pull request. Please help me understand or let me know if I am missing something here.
Screenshot:


Is the command shell doing something with ^ so that git rev-parse is only seeing the actual argument HEAD in both cases?

git log should show you both HEAD and the actual (distinct) parent of HEAD.

Since you mentioned you are new, is it possible that you only have a single commit on your branch at the moment?

No, I have multiple commits and the latest commit is by a merge pull request to the main branch.

Seems your first comment is correct as in when there is a ^ at the end of the command it is treating it as new line and just showing the commit related to HEAD. Thank you for the prompt help.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

^ is the cmd.exe escape character, like \ in unix. You typed ^ at the end of the line and cmd prompted you for the line continuation,
Say echo ^  (with the space on the end) to see what rev-parse saw.
Quote your arguments if they contain any of your shell's command-line-construction syntax you don't want to use that way.
